# Eloquent query where 'any value'

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, wildcard

Here I am trying to write a generic search query in a controller with multiple parameters, however the request might not have all of the parameters for the request. Is there a way to check if the value is not present and supply an a 'any' wildcard parameter for `where` to return 'all' results without having to write all the conditional combinations of the request?

For example, I am querying a table based on `n` params:

```
$data = Model::where('param1', $request->param1)
                   .where('param2', $request->param2)
                   .where('param3', $request->param3)

                   ....

                   .get();
```

Is there a way to provide some kind of wildcard if the parameter doesn't exist to tell the query builder to match everything?

Example:

```
$data = Model::where('param1', $request->param1 ? $request->param1 : 'wildcard')

                    ...

                    .get();
```

So for example if the request came with no parameters, it would query the table for everything, but if there were only one parameter, the resulting query would select based on the given parameter.

This would allow me to write one query instead of writing every combination of conditional queries to match the parameters.

Comment: Too much JavaScript (using dot instead of arrow on your code :-D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't recommend using some wildcard here (something like `param1 LIKE %`).

Try make something like this on your controller:

```
$allowedFilters = [
    'param1',
    'param2',
    /* ... */
];

$query = Model:: query();

foreach ($allowedFilters as $allowedFilter) {
    if ($request->has($allowedFilter)) {
        $query->where($allowedFilter, $request->get($allowedFilter));
    }
}

$data = $query->get();
```

This way you don't add unnecessary where clauses to your query, and also protects from SQL injection (and unwanted filters) by allowing just some column names.

Comment: Thank you, I found an article (https://m.dotdev.co/writing-advanced-eloquent-search-query-filters-de8b6c2598db) that describes a similar pattern, but I like your approach. Hope someone can find this question if they are in the same situation as me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some short research I [found an article](https://m.dotdev.co/writing-advanced-eloquent-search-query-filters-de8b6c2598db) that describes a pattern that solves my problem. Basically construct a query and chain building it up based on what has been supplied:

```
    $data = $data->newQuery();

    if ($request->has('param1')) {
        $data->where('param1', $request->input('param1'));
    }

    if ($request->has('param2')) {
        $data->where('company', $request->input('param2'));
    }

    if ($request->has('param3')) {
        $data->where('city', $request->input('param3'));
    }

    // Continue for all of the filters.

    // Get the results and return them.
    return $data->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save each parameter in a variable, taking into account that if the parameter is not present, the value for that variable will be `null`. Then in the query you can use the `when()` method, which will be false for a `null` value:

```
$param1 = $request->param1;
$param2 = $request->param2;

$data = Model::when($param1, function ($query) use ($param1) {
        $query->where('param1', $param1);
    })
    ->when($param2, function ($query) use ($param2) {
        $query->where('param2', $param2);
    })
    // ...
    ->get();
```

If none of the parameters is present, only `get()` will be executed, that is, it will bring all the records for that model